# Converting a 4 bit key to an 8 bit one in C

Tags: c

I am trying to convert a 4 bit key like "0110" to an 8 bit key like "0110 0110" where it reads in each character of the 4 bit key using getchar() and then converts it.

I have tried using a character that has an 8 bit key of just zeroes and then using bitwise OR with the given key to convert it, but this doesn't result in the right number.

```
char bit_key = 0x00;
printf("enter 4-bit key: ");
value = getchar();
while (i < 4) {
    bit_key = bit_key | (char) value;
    i++;
    value = getchar();
}
```

Comment: You are one step ahead of yourself. First make sure that you manage to read and store the 4bit key. Looking at the code you show, I seriously doubt it works. First write a program which only reads the 4bit key and outputs it. Then check that the input you give matches the output you get and expect. (Then multiply by 17.)

Comment: As far as I can tell, you expect getchar to behave differently than it does, read the spec.  You should double check initialising all variables. You should read up on the left shift operator `<<`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to convert the character value into an integer value. If you want to just assume the user will only enter either `1` or `0`, then you can simply change this line `bit_key = bit_key | (char)value;` to this line `bit_key = bit_key | (value - 48)` since the ascii value for 0 and 1 are 48 and 49 respectively.

You then need to make sure you are shifting over the value of `bit_key` by one bit every time a new bit is entered. This is missing from your original code and causes each bit entered to be or-ed with the previously entered bit. We can fix this by simply modifying the same line again to read `bit_key = (bit_key << 1) | (value - 48);`.

Finally, if you want the 4 bit key to be repeated for another 4 bits, its as simple as shifting the original over by 4 bits and bitwise or-ing it with the original. This can be done with the following line `bit_key = (bit_key << 4) | bit_key;` which can be put after the while loop.

In the end, your code looks like this:

```
char bit_key = 0x00;
printf("enter 4-bit key: ");
value = getchar();
while (i < 4) {
    bit_key = (bit_key << 1) | (value - 48);
    i++;
    value = getchar();
}

bit_key = (bit_key << 4) | bit_key;
```